# How to add carousel properly into a view in sencha touch 2?

Tags: gridview, sencha-touch-2, carousel

How can one add a instance of `Ext.Carousel` into a view in runtime in sencha touch 2.X.
If I do `v.add(c)` it seems to add the carousel into the view, but its contents won't show.
My view is currently defined as

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',

fullscreen: true,
config: {
    html: "Html"
}
});
```

Then I use `var main = Ext.create('MyApp.view.Main');` to instantiate it.
When I use `main.add(carouselObject);` it wont show the contents of the carousel, even though the carousel it self works fine when I add it to the screen without putting it into my main view.

Comment: Can you show the code of the view please ?

Comment: Thank you, can you give the code concerning the carouselObject too ?
On the top of my head, I would say try to set a `height` to both the carousel and the cards that you put in it.

Comment: @Saffron My carousel object only includes other carousels. Can I set the height for a `Ext.Carousel` object?

Comment: Yes you can, look at the doc, there is a `config` called `height`. I can't link the doc because I can't access it.
Also, try putting some html content in your carousels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like sencha needs to know the height and width of the components that I'm trying to put to my `Ext.Panel` object. After setting height and width for the `Ext.Carousel` component its contents show up properly.